# Using SSIS temp tables and use result set for the package?

Tags: ssis, ssms, temp-tables

Hi I am using complex SQL Server Query where i am joining temp tables and use within the package.

How can I use this result set in SSIS?

I can’t use Stored Procedure because I can’t get admin rights for that.

I can’t get this to work, don't know if it’s because I have more than one temp table and it generate a select 
http://www.sqlerudition.com/how-to-use-temp-table-in-ssis/

And this one doesn't work either,
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/

Comment: What error do you get when you use your query as the source?   Add the complete script of your query to your post.

Comment: Why not just using an `OLEDB Source` and set the source type as `SQL COMMAND` and use your query, even if it is complex